# Case on multiple variables at once bash

Tags: bash, array, case

I want to know if there is any way to case on multiple variables at once, like this:

```
#/bin/bash
arr1=(1 2)
arr2=(3 4)
foo=1
bar=2

case $foo && $bar in
    ${arr1[@]})
        echo "variables equal array 1!";;
    ${arr2[@]})
        echo "variables equal array 2!";;
    *)
        echo "variables do not exactly equal any array!";;
esac
```

I don't want to put `$foo` and `$bar` in an array themselves, but I can if I absolutely have to.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming `IFS` hasn’t been changed from its default value:

```
case "$foo $bar" in
"${arr1[*]}") echo "variables equal array 1!" ;;
"${arr2[*]}") echo "variables equal array 2!" ;;
*) echo "variables do not exactly equal any array!" ;;
esac
```

This is only reliable if the separator (a space) isn’t present in the individual values stored in each array.

Comment: And like always(?) when one tries to represent an array as a single string in a straightforward way, some restriction on possible values is needed. Here `foo=a; bar='b c'` gives the same string as `foo='a b'; bar=c`.

Comment: This also requires the variables to be in the same order as the array elements.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I wouldn't worry about array variables.

Second, you can use any separator you like, provided it doesn't appear in your variables.  I often use "/".

Something like:

```
case "$foo"/"$bar" in
(1/2) echo variables equal to first pattern\! ;;
(3/4) echo variables equal to second pattern\! ;;
(*) echo variables match no pattern. ;;
esac
```

This also then allows you to write wildcard entries fairly easily, like a line reading:

```
(1??/2??) echo variables are similar to the first pattern, but bigger\! ;;
```

Remember that the order of the patterns matters (first match wins), and that you want a separator that does not appear in your values.

Also, if you make your first pattern something like `(*/*/*)` you can test for your separator appearing in your values.

Answer (score 1):

You could compare the output of `typeset -p` to do array equality comparison:

```
case $(a=("$foo" "$bar"); typeset -p a) in
  ("$(a=("${arr1[@]}"); typeset -p a)") ...;;
  ("$(a=("${arr2[@]}"); typeset -p a)") ...;;
esac
```

With `zsh`, you can `j`oin the elements after applying `q`uoting to produce  a deterministic string representation of the arrays which you can then compare as strings without having to run `typeset -p` in a subshell:

```
case "${(q)foo} ${(q)bar}" in
  (${(j[ ])${(q)arr1}}) ...;;
  (${(j[ ])${(q)arr2}}) ...;;
esac
```